# How to create component that does't give focus to the Window

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have JTextField with FocusListener that call textfield.grabFocus() every time when textfield lose focus. But unfortunetly, it allow parent Window to react on user action. Is there any way to don't give the focus to the Window using only JTextField methods?

Comment: So, you want to make it so that once a text field has focus, it can never loose focus?  That sounds evil...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you don't want any other controls on your program to be usable while this field requires focus.  The problem is, each object is likely to have at least one event listener waiting for some action to occur, and stealing your focus away from you.

You can make all objects not focusable by setting `setFocusable(false)` for each object, but that will still allow events to be captured.

I'd override/replace (or possibly completely remove, if really necessary) the event listeners on all the other objects to only perform actions when the proper conditions are met (when your object *doesn't* require focus, if that would ever occur).  If overridden/replaced, each listener could then return focus to the JTextField if those conditions are not met.

Also, it is better to use `requestFocus()` or `requestFocusInWindow()` instead of `grabFocus()`.  See [JComponent grabFocus()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#grabFocus%28%29) and [JComponent requestFocus()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus%28%29) for more information.